# how to tell which file is being referenced/used in bash?

Tags: awk

I have the following code

```
awk -F ',' 'NR==FNR { a[$1]=$1; next}; $4 in a {print $0};' FileA FileB
```

FileA

```
a,1
ab,2
```

FileB

```
FieldA,FieldB,FieldC,FieldD
a,1,2,ab
a,1,4,c
b,1,2,ab
ab,1,3,d
```

The file returns me nothing.

Expected Output

```
a,1,2,ab
b,1,2,ab
```

However, if I change the code to

```
awk -F ',' 'NR==FNR { a[$1]=$1; next}; $1 in a {print $0};' FileA FileB
```

It does return data in FileB

```
a,1,2,ab
a,1,4,c
ab,1,3,d
```

What is going on here... I have been working with bash for about 2 weeks, still confused about this language a lot..

edit1:
GNU Awk 4.1.0, API: 1.0

Comment: How do you get "b,1,2,ab" in the output?

Comment: While `awk` is often used in `bash`, these questions seem to be about how `awk` works, not `bash` itself.  What version of `awk` do you have?  I don't see the same output you report with my `gawk`

Comment: That is my expected outcome since ab is in the first column of FileA

Comment: @dood that should be there because `$4` in that line is `ab` which matches a `$1` from the first file

Comment: @EricRenouf  bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.52(1)-release (i386-pc-solaris2.10)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: As noted though, this isn't about `bash`, this is about `awk`, so what version of that do you have, and please edit your question to include it instead of adding information to the comments

Comment: I bet you copied the `FN==FNR` trick from somewhere without understanding it. That's the problem. Go back to where you found it and read the explanation

Comment: Please post the first line of the output of `awk --version`. In my case (GNU Awk 4.1.3), the program produces exactly your expected output.

Comment: In my case (GNU Awk 3.1.5), your code works as it should.

Comment: This  produces the expected output and doesn't produce the output from the first file in the second command for both the versions of awk (`GNU Awk 3.1.8` and `20121220 (FreeBSD)`) that I tried

Comment: Can you check the lines of your input files end in `\n` character and not in `\r\n` characters?

Comment: FYI, awk always processes all input files sequentially, and the `NR==FNR {... next} ...` is just a trick to apply the first action (`a[$1]=$1`) _only_ to the first file, and the second pattern/action pair (`$4 in a {print $0}`) _only_ to the second file.

Comment: Works well on ideone which provides GNU Awk 4.1.1 API 1.1 : https://ideone.com/NjiOik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a Windows line ending issue and has nothing to do with the AWK version. That's why the first call returns nothing.

First fix your files (changes all `\r\n` to `\n`):

```
$ dos2unix FileA
$ dos2unix FileB
```

Then

```
$ awk -F ',' 'NR==FNR { a[$1]=$1; next}; $4 in a {print $0};' FileA FileB
```

will produce the expected output:

```
a,1,2,ab
b,1,2,ab
```

---

For installing `dos2unix`, e.g.:

- Mac: `brew install dos2unix`
- Linux: `apt-get install dos2unix`